# Design pattern for Realm persistence

Tags: ios, realm

I'm using Realm in a App and I'm trying to abstract much as possible so that in the future I can swap database providers without too much change.

This pattern has worked well although I'm concerned about the following.

- Is creating a new realm object everytime a overhead (My current understanding is that Realm Objects are cached internally)?
- Are there any problems with the way I'm using Realm ?
- Are there any better design patterns for my purpose ?

  ```
  public struct BookDataLayer: BookDataLayerProvider {

  func isBookAvailable(bookIdentifier: String) throws -> Bool {
      let database = try getDatabase()
      return !database.objects(Book).filter("identifier = %@", bookIdentifier).isEmpty
  }

  func createOrUpdateBook(bookIdentifier: String, sortIndex: Int) throws {
      let book = Book()
      Book.bookIdentifier = bookIdentifier
      Book.sortIndex = sortIndex
      try create(book, update: true)
  }}

  protocol BookDataLayerProvider : DataAccessLayer {
    func isBookAvailable(bookIdentifier: String) throws -> Bool
    func createOrUpdateBook(bookIdentifier: String, sortIndex: Int) throws n} 

    extension DataAccessLayer {

  func getDatabase() throws -> Realm {
      do {
          let realm = try Realm()
          // Advance the transaction to the most recent state
          realm.refresh()
          return realm
      } catch {
          throw DataAccessError.DatastoreConnectionError
      }
  }

  func create(object: Object, update: Bool = false) throws {
      let database = try self.getDatabase()

      do {
          database.beginWrite()
          database.add(object, update: update)
          // Commit the write transaction
          // to make this data available to other threads
          try database.commitWrite()
      } catch {
          throw DataAccessError.InsertError
      }
  }}

   // Usage
   let bookDataLayer = BookDataLayer()
   bookDataLayer.isBookAvailable("4557788")

   bookDataLayer.createOrUpdateBook("45578899", 10)
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a completely solid design pattern. It's pretty common for developers to abstract the data layer APIs way from their code in case they need to switch it out.

In response to your questions:

- You're correct. `Realm` object instances are internally cached, so you can easily call `let realm = try! Realm()` multiple times with very little overhead.
- Unless you've found a specific reason, it's probably not necessary to call `refresh()` on the Realm instance every time you use it. Realm instances on the main thread are automatically refreshed on each iteration of the run loop, so you only need to call `refresh()` if you're expecting changes on a background thread, or need to access changes before the current run loop has completed.
- 'Better' design patterns is probably a matter of opinion, but from what I've seen from other codebases, what you've got there is already great! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer me. I love Realm so far. Your answers are really helpful.

Comment: My pleasure! I'm glad you found my answers useful! God to hear you're enjoying Realm! Feel free to ask any more questions about it! :)